# Tensorflow: map_fn does not work in Graph mode during training, in Eager mode it does

Tags: python, tensorflow

I try to implement the discriminate loss as defined in https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.02551 (code examples in this post are very simplified).

The simplified loss function that works looks like this:

```
 def discriminative_loss_working(y_true, y_pred):
    # Compute the loss for only the first image in the batch

    prediction = y_pred[0]
    label = y_true[0]

    # Number of clusters in ground truth
    clusters,_ = tf.unique(tf.reshape(label, [-1]))

    # Compute cluster means and variances for each cluster
    def compute_mean(c):
        mask = tf.equal(label[:,:,0], c)
        masked_pixels = tf.boolean_mask(prediction, mask)
        cluster_mean = tf.reduce_mean(masked_pixels, axis=0)

        return cluster_mean

    cluster_means = tf.map_fn(compute_mean, clusters, dtype=(tf.float32))
    return tf.reduce_mean(cluster_means)
```

This works. However, this does only look to the first image of the batch. I want to have a batch with multiple images. Therefore the loss function looks like this now:

```
def discriminative_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    """Computes loss for a batch of images
    Args:
        y_true: (n, h, w) where each elements contains the ground truth instance id
        y_pred: (n, h, w, d) d-dimensional vector for each pixel for each image in the batch
    Returns:
        loss
    """
    # Compute the loss for each image in the batch
    def compute_loss(input):
        prediction = input[1]
        label = input[0]

        # Number of clusters in ground truth
        clusters,_ = tf.unique(tf.reshape(label, [-1]))

        # Compute cluster means and variances for each cluster
        def compute_mean(c):
            mask = tf.equal(label[:,:,0], c)
            masked_pixels = tf.boolean_mask(prediction, mask)
            cluster_mean = tf.reduce_mean(masked_pixels, axis=0)

            return cluster_mean

        cluster_means = tf.map_fn(compute_mean, clusters, dtype=(tf.float32))
        return tf.reduce_mean(cluster_means)

    # We want to know the loss for each image in the batch
    losses = tf.map_fn(compute_loss, (y_true,y_pred), dtype=(tf.float32))
    return losses
```

But this produces an error:

> c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
>   tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Resource
>   __per_step_6/_tensor_arraysloss/output_1_loss/map/while/map/TensorArray_1_3/N10tensorflow11TensorArrayE
>   does not exist.

How to solve this? The exact same loss function has no problems with eager execution. Note also that his only occurs during the backward pass. Using model.predict instead of model.fit works fine.

The full example to reproduce the issue:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def discriminative_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    """Computes loss for a batch of images
    Args:
        y_true: (n, h, w) where each elements contains the ground truth instance id
        y_pred: (n, h, w, d) d-dimensional vector for each pixel for each image in the batch
    Returns:
        loss
    """
    # Compute the loss for each image in the batch
    def compute_loss(input):
        prediction = input[1]
        label = input[0]

        # Number of clusters in ground truth
        clusters,_ = tf.unique(tf.reshape(label, [-1]))

        # Compute cluster means and variances for each cluster
        def compute_mean(c):
            mask = tf.equal(label[:,:,0], c)
            masked_pixels = tf.boolean_mask(prediction, mask)
            cluster_mean = tf.reduce_mean(masked_pixels, axis=0)

            return cluster_mean

        cluster_means = tf.map_fn(compute_mean, clusters, dtype=(tf.float32))
        return tf.reduce_mean(cluster_means)

    # We want to know the loss for each image in the batch
    losses = tf.map_fn(compute_loss, (y_true,y_pred), dtype=(tf.float32))
    return losses

def discriminative_loss_working(y_true, y_pred):
    # Compute the loss for only the first image in the batch

    prediction = y_pred[0]
    label = y_true[0]

    # Number of clusters in ground truth
    clusters,_ = tf.unique(tf.reshape(label, [-1]))

    # Compute cluster means and variances for each cluster
    def compute_mean(c):
        mask = tf.equal(label[:,:,0], c)
        masked_pixels = tf.boolean_mask(prediction, mask)
        cluster_mean = tf.reduce_mean(masked_pixels, axis=0)

        return cluster_mean

    cluster_means = tf.map_fn(compute_mean, clusters, dtype=(tf.float32))
    return tf.reduce_mean(cluster_means)

class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, input_shape):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=4, kernel_size=(1,1))

    def call(self, input):
        return self.conv(input)

input_shape = (1,128,128,3)
def my_gen():
    while True:
        x = np.random.rand(1,input_shape[1], input_shape[2],3)
        y = np.random.randint(11000, 11015, (input_shape[1], input_shape[2],1))
        yield x,y

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(my_gen, (tf.float32, tf.float32))
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(1)
train_dataset = train_dataset.repeat()

model = MyModel(input_shape=input_shape)

# This is a fix to make loading weights possible
# x = tf.zeros((1,) + input_shape)
x = tf.zeros(input_shape)
y = model(x)

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.0001)
model.compile(loss=discriminative_loss,optimizer=optimizer)
model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=5, steps_per_epoch=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I also met this problem when I use map_fn and RNN layer in keras at the same time. But I still unknown the reason. Then I use `reshape()` instead of the `map_fn()` to resolve this issue.